# Query case insensitive with Sequelize in Node using MariaDB database

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I'm new in Sequelize and after digging a lot I could not find a way to write a query using *LOWER* and *LIKE* at the same time.

I want to write something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM acessories
 WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%xyz%' 
    OR LOWER(description) LIKE '%xyz%'
 ORDER BY name
```

I wrote the code like this, but I can't use the LOWER function:

```
const getAcessories = await Acessories.findAndCountAll({
        limit,
        offset: start,
        order: [["name", "ASC"]],
        where: {
          [Sequelize.Op.or]: [
            {
              name: {
                [Sequelize.Op.like]: `%${search}%`
              },
              description: {
                [Sequelize.Op.like]: `%${search}%`
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      });
```

Edit: Creation table command:

select * from atm_usuarios;

```
CREATE TABLE `acessories` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `in_value` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `out_value` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 collate=utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Any help?

Comment: `<snide-remark>`Notice how the SQL is more concise than the 3rd party representation of it?`</snide-remark>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *where* clause for your query can be written as follow in Sequelize.JS:

```
const Utils = Sequelize.Utils;
const whereClause = {
    [Op.or]: [
        new Utils.Where(
            new Utils.Fn('LOWER', new Utils.Col('name')), {[Op.like]: `%${search}%`}
        ),
        new Utils.Where(
            new Utils.Fn('LOWER', new Utils.Col('description')), {[Op.like]: `%${search}%`}
        )
    ]
}
```

If you have an instance of `Sequelize` around, you can also write this using static methods available on the instance as:

```
const whereClause = {
    [Op.or]: [
        sequelize.where(
            sequelize.fn('LOWER', sequelize.col('name')), {[Op.like]: `%${search}%`}
        ),
        sequelize.where(
            sequelize.fn('LOWER', sequelize.col('description')), {[Op.like]: `%${search}%`}
        )
    ]
}
```

This can be used like so:

```
const getAcessories = await Acessories.findAndCountAll({
    limit,
    offset: start,
    order: [["name", "ASC"]],
    where: whereClause
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't need `LOWER` at all.

If the `COLLATION` of the columns are "case insensitive", then simply do the tests without using `LOWER()` or `UPPER()`.

To see the collation (and other things), use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

One way to test it is to try with `%xyz%` and with `%XYZ%`.  I predict that both will give you the same results, hence you have a case insensitive collation.

**Specifically**

The problem is with `COLLATE utf8_bin` in the table definition.

Neither of the links in the Comments is relevant.  One refers to the "columnstore" engine, which is specifically not used for the table.  The other refers to "identifier" names -- such as table and column names, not column contents.

Comment: Collation works in MySQL, but not in MariaDB if it is running on Linux :/ I tried.

Comment: @JoubertVasconcelos - Oh???  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE acessories` and the generated SQL for the `SELECT`.  (I am familiar with MySQL and MariaDB, but not Sequelize.  I would be very surprised if MySQL and MariaDB differed in this area!)

Comment: I edited the question to add the create table instruction. Be sure, mariaDB is case-sensitive in Linux, but not in Windows: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/identifier-case-sensitivity/

Comment: They have an open ticket in their Jira board with a request for this feature: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MCOL-495

Comment: @JoubertVasconcelos - See my added text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ILIKE? You can see the docs and search ILIKE: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but ILIKE only works in Postgres and I'm using mariaDB.